Value does not live long enough for lifetime borrow
I'm having trouble with this Rust code when running cargo test
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::{Arc, Mutex, Weak}};

    struct Node<'b> {
        clients: Mutex<Vec<Weak<Client<'b>>>>
    }

    impl<'b> Node<'b> {
        pub fn new_action_client(&self) -> Arc<Client<'b>> {
            // let number = n.to_owned();
            let client = Arc::new(Client::new());
            { self.clients.lock().unwrap() }.push(Arc::downgrade(&client));
            client
        }
    }

    struct Client<'a> {
        closures: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, Box<dyn FnOnce() -> () + 'a>>>>
    }

    impl<'a> Client<'a> {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                closures: Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()))
            }
        }

        fn add(&self, key: String, entry: impl FnOnce() -> () + 'a) {
            { self.closures.lock().unwrap() }.insert(key, Box::new(entry));
        }

        fn add_method(&'a self) {
            let key = String::from("1"); 
            let entry = Box::new(|| -> () { println!("closures={:?}", self.closures.lock().unwrap().len()); });
            { self.closures.lock().unwrap() }.insert(key, entry);
        }

        async fn execute(&self, method: &str) -> () {
            // self.closures.iter().for_each(|c| -> () { (c)() });
            let closure_option = { self.closures.lock().unwrap() }.remove(method);
            match closure_option {
                Some(c) => (c)(),
                None => println!("None to run"),
            }
        }
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn an_async_function_runs_ok() {
        let node = Node { clients: Mutex::new(Vec::new()) };
        let client = node.new_action_client();
        let entry = || -> () { println!("1") };
        client.add("a".to_string(), entry);
        client.add_method();
    }
}

Here is the Rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8bd04a98de36637be15dd1ef2563fad
The error is:
error[E0597]: `client` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:91:9
   |
88 |         let client = node.new_action_client();
   |             ------ binding `client` declared here
...
91 |         client.add_method();
   |         ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
92 |     }
   |     -
   |     |
   |     `client` dropped here while still borrowed
   |     borrow might be used here, when `client` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `Arc`

It doesn't seem like it's possible to call execute at all when borrowing self for 'a.
Also if this is not idiomatic Rust, please let me know.

You're trying to create a self-referential struct, which is prohibited.
